# How to vmap over cho_solve and cho_factor?

Tags: python, jax

The following error appears because of the last line of code below:

> jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected...
>
> The problem arose with the `bool` function.

It looks like it is due to the `lower` return value from `cho_factor`, which [`_cho_solve`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jax/_src/scipy/linalg.html#cho_solve) (note underscore) requires as static.

I'm new to jax, so I was hoping that vmap-ing `cho_factor` into `cho_solve` would just work. What have I done wrong here?

```py
import jax

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
k_y = jax.random.normal(key, (100, 10, 10))
y = jax.random.normal(key, (100, 10, 1))

matmul = jax.vmap(jax.numpy.matmul)
cho_factor = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.cho_factor)
cho_solve = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.cho_solve)

k_y = matmul(k_y, jax.numpy.transpose(k_y, (0, 2, 1)))
chol, lower = cho_factor(k_y)
result = cho_solve((chol, lower), y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in each case, `lower` is a static scalar that should not be mapped over. So if you specify `in_axes` and `out_axes` so that `lower` is mapped over axis `None`, the `vmap` should work:

```py
cho_factor = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.cho_factor, out_axes=(0, None))
cho_solve = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.cho_solve, in_axes=((0, None), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't manage to get `cho_factor` and `cho_solve` working, but worked around it using `cholesky` and `solve_triangular`:

```py
  cholesky = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.cholesky, in_axes=(0, None))
  solve_tri = jax.vmap(jax.scipy.linalg.solve_triangular, in_axes=(0, 0, None, None))

  L = cholesky(k_y, True)
  result2 = solve_tri(L, solve_tri(L, y, 0, True), 1, True)
```