# How to vectorize cho_solve?

Tags: python, jax

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76458629/how-to-vmap-over-cho-solve-and-cho-factor/76471111) solved my problem of using `vmap` on `cho_solve`, is it possible to `vectorize` `cho_solve`, or does the definition of `cho_solve` preclude it from being vectorized? `vectorize` seems to need the arguments to all be arrays, whereas `cho_solve` takes a tuple as the first argument?

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy as jsp

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
key, subkey = jax.random.split(key)

k_y = jax.random.normal(subkey, (3, 5, 10, 10))
y = jnp.broadcast_to(jnp.eye(10), k_y.shape)

matmul = jnp.vectorize(jnp.matmul, signature='(a,b),(b,c)->(a,c)')
cholesky = jnp.vectorize(jsp.linalg.cholesky, excluded={1}, signature='(d,d)->(d,d)')
cho_solve = jnp.vectorize(jsp.linalg.cho_solve, signature='(d,d),(d,d)->(d,d)')  # what to put here?

k_y = matmul(k_y, jnp.moveaxis(k_y, -1, -2))
chol = cholesky(k_y, True)
result = cho_solve((chol, True), y)
```

> ValueError: All input arrays must have the same shape.

My use case is that I have an unspecified amount of "batch" dimensions that I want to `vmap` over, and `vectorize` handles the auto broadcasting beautifully. I can once again write my own cho_solve using `solve_triangular` but this seems like a waste. Is it possible for `vectorize` to have a similar interface to vmap, which can take nested signatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `vectorize` directly with `cho_solve`. The [`vectorize` API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) requires that the function take arrays as an argument, while `cho_solve` takes a tuple as the first argument. The only way you could use `vectorize` with this function is to wrap it in one with a different API. For example:

```py
cho_solve = jnp.vectorize(
    lambda chol, flag, y: jsp.linalg.cho_solve((chol, flag), y),
    excluded={1}, signature='(d,d),(d,d)->(d,d)')
result = cho_solve(chol, True, y)
```

Comment: Would that give the same benefits of the vmapping under the hood, or is that essentially doing the loop from my answer?

Comment: `jnp.vectorize` is built on `vmap`, so it would basically be the same in the end; for some discussion see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118863/2937831.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give that a shot. I thought in this case it might just be syntactic sugar like numpy's vectorize is, but it seems not! Thanks for a great library, I'm loving it :)

Comment: `jnp.vectorize` is exactly the same API as numpy's `vectorize`, that's where it gets it's restriction on function signature. For what it's worth, `vmap` would be able to handle the `cho_solve` normal argument structure directly.

Comment: But `vmap` isn't able to handle the arbitrary batch dimensions, right, unless I'm missing something? In that SO you linked you had to explicitly `vmap` twice, which I thought `vectorize` was built to do under the hood? Is there a performance hit from using `vectorize` over multiple `vmap`s?

I want to write the function once, and then call it with multiple different batch sizes, without having to explicitly specify all the `vmap` combinations, is `vectorize` the right tool for that?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. You’re correct that vmap and vectorize have different semantics. There is no performance issue with vectorize compared to multiple vmaps, because it’s implemented via multiple vmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `solve_triangular` solution I managed:

```py
solve_tri = jnp.vectorize(
  jsp.linalg.solve_triangular, excluded={2, 3}, signature='(d,d),(d,d)->(d,d)')
chol = cholesky(k_y, True)
result2 = solve_tri(chol, solve_tri(chol, y, 0, True), 1, True)
result3 = jnp.array([
  jsp.linalg.cho_solve((chol[a, b], True), y[a, b])
  for a in range(k_y.shape[0])
  for b in range(k_y.shape[1])
]).reshape(k_y.shape)
print(jnp.allclose(result2, result3))
```

> True